# Using Android Looper still throwing "Can't create handler inside..."

Tags: android

I have a looper and handler:

```
private Handler handler;

public class LooperThread extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Looper.prepare();
        handler = new Handler()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message message)
            {
                updateUI(message.obj);
            }
        };

        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

In my MainActivity I then call:

```
new LooperThread().start();
new Thread(new WorkerTask()).start();
```

Where WorkerTask implements Runnable.

Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare().

Inside my workerTask it is throwing the error on the second line:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(activity.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

Comment: I think this post answers my question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476847/error-cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare

Comment: can you post the code of worker task?your LooperThread is fine

Answer (score 0):

If this is in Activity or fragment you can simply use runOnUiThread to update ui.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    updateUI(message.obj);
  }
});
```

Or to use it with your existing code:

```
private Handler handler;

public class LooperThread extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Looper.prepare();
        handler = new Handler()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message message)
            {
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    updateUI(message.obj);
                }
                });
            }
        };

        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```