# Getting error on requestLocationUpdates in JobInetentService in Oreo

Tags: android, location, android-8.0-oreo, android-gps, jobintentservice

I have written a GPS **based** location Service in which I am calling `requestLocationUpdates` to get updated location and its working properly, but when I targeted the **Android Oreo** then I have replaced `Service` with `JobIntentService`.But when I am running the application then getting below error. Please provide the solution.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:361)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:204)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:118)
                                                                           at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.<init>(LocationManager.java:234)
                                                                           at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.<init>(LocationManager.java:234)
                                                                           at android.location.LocationManager.wrapListener(LocationManager.java:872)
                                                                           at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:885)
                                                                           at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:470)
                                                                           at com.example.services.LocationService.onHandleWork(LocationService.java:49)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:391)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:382)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

My Class

```
public class LocationService extends JobIntentService {
LocationManager MylocationManager;
LocationListenerClass MylocationListener;
Context context;
Location mLocation;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = this;
}

public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
   enqueueWork(context, LocationService.class, Constants.JOB_ID, work);

}

@Override
protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    } else {
        MylocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        MylocationListener = new LocationListenerClass();
        MylocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 36000000, 5000, MylocationListener);

    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

public class LocationListenerClass implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (location == null) {
            return;
        }
       mLocation = location;
        try {
            if (MylocationManager != null) {
                MylocationManager.removeUpdates(MylocationListener);

                MylocationManager = null;
            }
          } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        if (MylocationManager != null) {
            MylocationManager.removeUpdates(MylocationListener);

            MylocationManager = null;
        }


    }
}

}
```

And I am starting service by below code

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, LocationService.class);
LocationService.enqueueWork(context, intent1);
```

Comment: I did;n't find out error, but this crash happens if you perform some UI task in background thread.

Comment: But i am not performing any UI task

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29691963/569332) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the implementation of LocationManager is creating a Handler.  A Handler can only be created on a Thread that has called Looper.loop().  For example, the UI thread (where the framework calls it) or a HandlerThread (which is made to use Loopers).  An IntentService is run on its own thread, and does not have a Looper.  You need to make the call to requestLocation updates on another Thread, either a HandlerThread you create or the UI thread would be easiest.

Comment: Will you provide the example? How to create Handler...?